# csv-mode: do not split line on newline inside quoted field

Tags: replace, csv

I'm using the latest `csv-mode` in Emacs 25.3.1 in centos 6.10.  The problem is that I have many fields that are long documentation strings and many of them have embedded newlines.  This messed up `csv-mode` and causes affected rows to be split into multiple lines in the buffer.

How can I make this usable?  Is there a way to replace newlines embedded in strings with some other character (e.g. `|`) when reading the file and then put them back when writing the file?

Answer (score 1):

The following code replaces newlines in quoted fields with the customizable string `csv+-quoted-newline` in `csv-mode-hook`.

It does the inverse replacement in `write-contents-functions`.

Excerpt of the doc string of `write-contents-functions`:

> List of functions to be called before writing out a buffer to a file.
>
> Only used by `save-buffer'.  If one of them returns non-nil, the
>   file is considered already written and the rest are not called
>   and neither are the functions in`write-file-functions'.  This
>   hook can thus be used to create save behavior for buffers that
>   are not visiting a file at all.
>
> This variable is meant to be used for hooks that pertain to the
>   buffer's contents, not to the particular visited file; thus,
>   `set-visited-file-name' does not clear this variable; but changing the
>   major mode does clear it.

```el
(defcustom csv+-quoted-newline "\^@"
  "Replace for newlines in quoted fields."
  :group 'sv
  :type 'string)

(defun csv+-quoted-newlines (&optional b e inv)
  "Replace newlines in quoted fields of region B E by `csv+-quoted-newline'.
B and E default to `point-min' and `point-max', respectively.
If INV is non-nil replace quoted `csv+-quoted-newline' chars by newlines."
  (interactive
   (append (when (region-active-p)
         (list (region-begin)
           (region-end)))
       prefix-arg))
  (unless b (setq b (point-min)))
  (unless e (setq e (point-max)))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char b)
    (let ((from (if inv csv+-quoted-newline "\n"))
      (to (if inv "\n" csv+-quoted-newline)))
      (while (search-forward from e t)
    (when (nth 3 (save-excursion (syntax-ppss (1- (point)))))
      (replace-match to))))))

(defsubst csv+-quoted-newlines-write-contents ()
  "Inverse operation of `csv+-quoted-newlines' for the full buffer."
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (let ((file (buffer-file-name))
        (contents (buffer-string)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert contents)
      (csv+-quoted-newlines (point-min) (point-max) t)
      (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file)))))
  (set-visited-file-modtime)
  (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
  t ;; File contents has been written (see `write-contents-functions').
  )

(defun csv+-setup-quoted-newlines ()
  "Hook function for `csv-mode-hook'.
Transform newlines in quoted fields to `csv+-quoted-newlines'
when reading files and the other way around when writing contents."
  (add-hook 'write-contents-functions #'csv+-quoted-newlines-write-contents t t)
  (let ((modified-p (buffer-modified-p)))
    (csv+-quoted-newlines)
    (set-buffer-modified-p modified-p)))

(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook #'csv+-setup-quoted-newlines)
```

Tested with Emacs 26.1, csv-mode 1.7 and the following csv-file:

```
11, 12, "Some
string", 14
21, 22, "Another
string", 24
31, 32, "And just another
string.", 34
41, 42, "And just another
string.", 44
```

Emacs displays the file after `find-file` as follows:

```
11, 12, "Some^@string", 14
21, 22, "Another^@string", 24
31, 32, "And just another^@string.", 34
41, 42, "And just another^@string.", 44
```

Thereby, `^@` is the null character. You can input the null character by <kbd>C-q C-@</kbd> to insert further newlines in quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks - this worked great.  One caveat: after saving the file, I have to revert-buffer before continuing to edit the file or I get a message asking me if I want to edit a file that has changed on disk.

Comment: @DavidR I've added `set-visited-file-modtime` to `csv+-quoted-newlines-write-contents`. That avoids the problem with buffer-reverting (at least in my tests).

Comment: Please use `add-hook` rather than `add-to-list` when manipulating hooks.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the comment. I have changed `add-to-list` to `add-hook`. I was a bit irritated by the fact that `write-contents-functions` is buffer-local per se. But, a search in the Emacs lisp dir acknowledged that `write-contents-functions` is set via `add-hook`.

Comment: @Stefan Do you know what the reason is for making hooks buffer local? Maybe `write-contents-functions` looks formally better as buffer local hook. But, technically that does not matter with `add-hook`, does it?

Comment: You don't "make hooks buffer-local": instead, hooks always have a global and a local part and when you `add-hook` you use the `local` argument to tell when you want to add the function to the local or the global part of the hook.  For historical reasons, some hooks have no global part, tho this phenomenon should hopefully disappear over time.